# DNS Issues, how to detect the cause of the issue

Tags: domain-name-system

I've migrated from a VPS to another VPS. After this migraton the website is in most of the cases only accessible when using the Google public DNS (8.8.8.8 - 8.8.4.4).

The migration have been done 6 days ago.

How can I start to investigate what is wrong?

Best Regards,
André Lopes

Comment: And the domain is....

Comment: "most of the cases"? And Google Public DNS resolver is not a DNS troubleshooting tool. Use online diagnostics tools: https://www.zonemaster.net/   https://dnsviz.net/

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS hasn't been updated correctly. Use something like [IntoDNS](https://intodns.com) to analyse how your domains are resolving and any problems arising from this.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check the TTL for each record. I guess you have a long TTL on the records and you will get a cached result. When using google DNS, they probably have not cached your old records and thats why you get the new ones.  You can use mxtoolbox.com to check your dns records. If they are correct here, then its caching and TTL causing your problems